# error C2165: 'left-side modifier' : cannot modify pointers to data

Tags: c++, boost, callback

I was trying this piece of code

demo.hpp

```
#ifndef DEMO_HPP
#define DEMO_HPP

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::function<void(vector<int>)>func;
typedef void (_stdcall *Callback);

class funcPointer
{
public:

    void add_call(int, func);
    void call_back(int, Callback);
    void push_elements();

    vector<int> vec;
};

#endif
```

demo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "demo.hpp"

void funcPointer::add_call(int number, func f)
{
    cout<<"number: "<<number << endl;

    f(vec);
}

void funcPointer::push_elements()
{
    vec.push_back(11);
    vec.push_back(12);
    vec.push_back(13);
}

void funcPointer::call_back(int x, Callback call)
{
    cout << "x: " << x <<endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "demo.hpp"

void display(vector<int> v)
{
    vector<int> ::iterator it;
    for(it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout<< *it <<endl;
    }
}

void Inside_callback()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    funcPointer *fun = new funcPointer;
    fun->push_elements();
    fun->add_call(24, boost::bind(display, _1));
    fun->call_back(10, &Inside_callback);

    return 0;
}
```

while compiling I got the following error:

```
e:\vs_c++\boost_func_ptr\boost_func_ptr\demo.hpp(12): error C2165: 'left-side modifier' : cannot modify pointers to data
```

I am not able to understand what this error is, and how to get rid of it.
Can somebody help me to get rid of this error??

Answer (score 0):

You have to define type of Callback in following way:

```
typedef void (_stdcall *Callback)();
```

You should also modify declaration of Inside_callback in following way for code to compile:

```
void _stdcall Inside_callback()
```